# How to remotely enter email credentials in django?

Tags: django, server

My web app is deployed by the computer team but developed by me. It is essential that the emails are sent using my team's email id. Hence, I am using a form to enter credentials into a safe file only accessible to my user.
This is my settings file
from config

```
parser import ConfigParser
EMAIL_CREDENTIAL_CONFIG = "credentials.ini"
def credential(attr):
    config = ConfigParser()
    try:
        config.read(EMAIL_CREDENTIAL_CONFIG)
        return config["DEFAULT"][attr]
    except KeyError:
        pass
EMAIL_HOST_USER = credential("EMAIL_HOST_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = credential("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")
```

The issue is that these values are loaded only when the server starts and I cannot remotely update it without using an ssh terminal and manually entering the file location. Can you suggest alternatives to either reload the email credentials automatically or to keep the creds safe from anyone having access to the server pc?

Answer (score 0):

You could store your credential file in your server and give read permission only to the webserver running django.

Comment: Since I'm not deploying the server I can't write the credentials before I hand over the project to the technical team.